# Unable to retrieve DDL SelectedValue bound in ASPX after Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following markup / code block in the ASPX file.
The binding of the ddl is triggered after Page_Load event which is in the code behind file.
This results me not able to get the selected value of the dropdownlist if I were to use such flow.

However for some purpose I require it to work this way.
Any idea how I could get the dropdownlist selected value when a post back is being triggered (click of the button)?

```
Page URL: page.aspx?para1=0&para2=value
```

ASPX PAGE

```
<% 
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["para1"]) == 0)
    {
        ddl.DataValueField = "value"; 
        ddl.DataTextField = "text"; 
        ddl.DataSource = ds; //ds is valid, exact code not shown
        ddl.DataBind(); 
    } else {
        //write in this area
        Response.Write("Not 0");
    }
%> 
<form runat="server" id="user_form" class="form-horizontal"> 
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl"> 
        </asp:DropDownList> 
        <%-- this button will call btnSave_Click to get the ddl's value--%>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
</form>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
        //do my stuff 
    } 
} 

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue); 
    //do my stuff 
}
```

The ASPX Page code block will run after Page_Load / page's lifecycle, then will determine what to do base on the url parameters.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What failed when using ViewState? If you want to use the value after a page load you need to keep it somehow, and you can use ViewState for this.

Comment: enabling viewstate for dropdownlist, but unable to retrieve when on a button click that triggers post back via ddl.selectedvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always throw in a hidden object and use jquery to copy the value to the hidden value based on a certain action without a postback and would do it client side like it sounds like you want it to do